# Samba without central server?

Tags: windows, linux, samba

I have found Samba to be a real pain to keep working at home (having half a dosen Windows & Linux computers)

Without a central server, samba keeps moving the domain master browser as computers are shutdown (or just removed from the network) and that makes it not work (**). The result is that samba is not working more that it works, both for Windows and Linux.

On a pure Windows network, the stuff just works. (Even though Windows prefers to have a central server to talk to.)

What settings are needed to have samba work without a central server?

How does Windows handle this?

---

** There are two levels of "not work" that occur on the network (even at the same time on different computers):

1. Unable to browse list of workgroups.
2. Unable to mount share ('Unable to get share list from server').

Also, linux log files (e.g. syslog) fill up with lines like

```
Dec 24 18:53:47 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   *****
Dec 24 18:53:47 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   
Dec 24 18:53:47 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   Samba server MYWIFIPLUG is now a domain master browser for workgroup W on subnet 10.1.1.2
Dec 24 18:53:47 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   
Dec 24 18:53:47 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   *****
Dec 24 18:54:00 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]: [2011/12/24 18:54:00.120652,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:416(become_local_master_fail2)
Dec 24 18:58:39 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]: [2011/12/24 18:58:39.421309,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_dmb.c:292(become_domain_master_browser_bcast)
Dec 24 18:58:39 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   become_domain_master_browser_bcast:
Dec 24 18:58:39 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   Attempting to become domain master browser on workgroup W on subnet 192.168.1.1
Dec 24 18:58:39 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]: [2011/12/24 18:58:39.422170,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_dmb.c:305(become_domain_master_browser_bcast)
Dec 24 18:58:39 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   become_domain_master_browser_bcast: querying subnet 192.168.1.1 for domain master browser on workgroup W
Dec 24 18:58:39 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]: [2011/12/24 18:58:39.423376,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_dmb.c:235(become_domain_master_query_success)
Dec 24 18:58:39 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   become_domain_master_query_success:
Dec 24 18:58:39 dreamplug-debian nmbd[2944]:   There is already a domain master browser at IP 192.168.1.35 for workgroup W registered on subnet 192.168.1.1.
```

Comment: Your problem description is not helpful. All you say is that it makes it "not work". What exactly goes wrong? What problems do you have?

Comment: We'll also need a bit more of an idea of set up. How many Windows/Linux computers, are there any that are left on that could be set to try and always be the master browser?

Comment: edited question with details